# How do I remove myself as MR participant in Gitlab? (NOT notifications toggle)

Tags: email, gitlab, notifications, merge-request

My project frequently demotes MRs back to Draft when the dev needs to do substantial work before further review. I get removed as a reviewer but not as a participant and so I still get notifications/emails for every little thing that happens to the MR. But if I shut off notifications then I won't get notified when the MR is ready for me to review it again. How do I remove myself as a participant?
I don't want to shut off notifications forever for the MR, I just want to NOT be on the participant list until I'm manually added back to it.